# WIX How to add Property in the patch

Tags: properties, wix, windows-installer, patch

In the released MSI, I had the hard-coded port number, e.g.

```
<Property Id="HTTP_PORT1" Secure="yes" Value="1000" />
<Component Id="my.exe" Guid="*" Win64="yes" >
  <File Id="my.exe" KeyPath="yes" Source="my.exe" />
  <RegistryValue Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\MyCompany" Name="Port1" Value="[HTTP_PORT1]" Type="integer" />
  <RegistryValue Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\MyCompany" Name="Port2" Value="9000" Type="integer" />
</Component>
```

And for the patch, my Patch.wxs looked like this:

```
<PatchFamily Id="Rollup" Version="1.0.100" Supersede="yes">
  <ComponentRef Id="my.exe"/>
</PatchFamily>
```

When I manually change those regs to "1111" and "9999" and applied the patch MSP, those Port1 and Port2 were set back to "1000" and "9000" respectively. So I changed "HTTP_PORT1" and added "INT_HTTP_PORT2" like this:

```
<Property Id="HTTP_PORT1" Secure="yes" Value="#1000" >
  <RegistrySearch Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\MyCompany" Name="Port1" Type="raw" Win64="yes" />
</Property>
<Property Id="INT_HTTP_PORT2" Secure="yes" Value="#9000" >
  <RegistrySearch Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\MyCompany" Name="Port2" Type="raw" Win64="yes" />
</Property>
<Component Id="my.exe" Guid="*" Win64="yes" >
  <File Id="my.exe" KeyPath="yes" Source="my.exe" />
  <RegistryValue Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\MyCompany" Name="Port1" Value="[HTTP_PORT1]" Type="string" />
  <RegistryValue Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\MyCompany" Name="Port2" Value="[INT_HTTP_PORT2]" Type="string" />
</Component>
```

And I changed Patch.wxs like this:

```
<PatchFamily Id="Rollup" Version="1.0.100" Supersede="yes">
  <ComponentRef Id="my.exe"/>
  <PropertyRef Id="HTTP_PORT1"/>
  <PropertyRef Id="INT_HTTP_PORT2"/>
</PatchFamily>
```

However, both Port1 and Port2 are changed back to the original values (although Port1 is now REG_SZ.)
Is this an expected behavior? Is it possible to make it work in the patch without using Type1 custom action?

Answer (score 0):

The executable in that component is the keypath item. I'd verify that you increased the version of that exe because it effectively controls whether that component is updated. You could create a verbose log of the patch install to see exactly what's going on.

What you need to look for in the verbose log is what it says about my.exe, whether it's Overwrite or something else. Also, note that if the component rules were broken in the patch it will effectively result in nothing being patched. You will see SELMGR in the log if that's the case.

Comment: I already verified that exe had a bigger version #. The logfile doesn't say anything except WriteRegistryValues with the original value. Those 2 properties were listed in "Property(S):" and "Property(C):" with the same values.

Comment: It's my.exe in the log you need to look at. It's in the patch so it will overwrite the previous version or not.